# Google Polylines, bad conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gps, rubygems

I tried to use [this Ruby Gem](https://github.com/joshuaclayton/polylines) and encountered a problem with it. Sometimes, I have problems with the output, it seems like there is an issue with rounding when i decode a polyline. If i compare with the array received from the official "Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility", sometimes, I haven't the same result.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility

For example, the string of the polylines used is :

```
"eyhiHkx}LcGdBGHAFa@WdCeL?IACKOH_@NF?PFqCfE}RTwB?Y|@@v@K`@Yn@oABcAGmAQ{@IiA@cBhGoXtMom@`TyaA^sBB}@Ga@KYMWk@i@y@iAOq@E{ALoB\\eCZwAJF\\uABM^TjLtI`ErCrBtAhAl@l@RTBNCf@]pF{EvMgMjI{Id@[XGxCa@`VyEpHwAtGkA|SyDzCm@X@NFPRnEzFNVJh@@|@oDdPlBpAe@c@D{@^FPH|EhG"
```

See the attached two screenshot to see the difference:
[image]

[image]

The first one is from the official google utilities and the second is using the gem.

You can see that the rounding of the GPS coordinates are not the same:

```
48.87205,2.3006

[48.87205000000001, 2.300600000000001]
```

Has anyone ever experienced the same thing or does anyone know a way I could transform the result so they are the same without loosing coordinates precision in order to compare two polylines?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered on the project github issues: https://github.com/joshuaclayton/polylines/issues/3